# error when using <%#Eval("")%> asp.net

Tags: asp.net, razor, web, webforms

Hello

I get Error usign <%#Eval("ComlainnID")%>

I got error on every line which have <%#Eval%>

My GridView code is this

```
      <asp:GridView CssClass="tbl" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ComplainID" 
      DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ItemType="q" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" ID="gv" style="direction: ltr"
       OnPageIndexChanging="gv_PageIndexChanging" AllowPaging="True" EmptyDataText="No Complain Found" 
        BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px" PageSize="25" 
      OnDataBinding="gv_DataBinding" OnRowDataBound ="gv_DataBound" AllowSorting="True" OnRowEditing="gv_RowEditing"

      >
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>

            <asp:ImageField  HeaderStyle-CssClass="border" HeaderText="Photo"  DataImageUrlField="ImagePath" ItemStyle-Height="50px" ItemStyle-Width="50px">
                <ItemStyle  CssClass="border"  Height="50px" Width="50px">
                </ItemStyle>
            </asp:ImageField>


             <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" EditText="Reply" ShowEditButton="True" 
                 HeaderStyle-CssClass="border" ItemStyle-CssClass="border" >

            </asp:CommandField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>

                    <asp:Label Text='<%#Eval("ComplainID")%>' ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>


    </asp:GridView>
```

The Error is on line

```
             <asp:Label Text='<%#Eval("ComplainID")%>' ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

The Error is :

```
        Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'q' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

This is web application in .NET Framework 4.6

Comment: post exact code. This code doesn't seems to give this error.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably remove this from your gridview properties:

```
ItemType="q"
```